# Pandas: groupby and concat strings with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset

```
id   category   description   status
11   A          Text_1        Finished
11   A          Text_2        Pause
11   A          Text_3        Started
22   A          Text_1        Pause
33   B          Text_1        Finished
33   B          Text_2        Finished
```

And I want to group data with `id` and concat `description` only for raws with `status = 'Finished'`

So desired output is

```
id    category   description
11    A          Text_1
22    A          
33    B          Text_1 Text_2
```

I can concat it using

```
data.groupby(['id', 'category'])['description'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

But how can I use condition inside this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can filter before `groupby` then `reindex` with the missing groups

```
out = data.loc[data.status == 'Finished'].groupby(['id', 'category'])['description'].apply(' '.join).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(data[['id','category']].drop_duplicates()),fill_value= ' ').reset_index()
Out[70]: 
   id category    description
0  11        A         Text_1
1  22        A               
2  33        B  Text_1 Text_2
```

Comment: You can remove `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby.apply` with a conditional and a default value if the group is empty after filtering:

```
out = (df
 .groupby(['id', 'category'])
 .apply(lambda g: ' '.join(d['description'])
                  if len(d:=g[g['status'].eq('Finished')])
                  else '' )
 .reset_index(name='description')
 )
```

Output:

```
   id category    description
0  11        A         Text_1
1  22        A               
2  33        B  Text_1 Text_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```py
key = ['id', 'category']
df2 = data[key].drop_duplicates().join(
    data.query("status == 'Finished'").groupby(key).description.apply(' '.join), 
    on=key).fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Explanation:

- use `query()` to filter on status for "Finished", use `groupby()` to group by the `key` [id, category], then use your `str.join()` logic on the `description` column values within each group
- use a de-duped version of the `key` columns and `DataFrame.join()` to expand the filtered results to contains all `key` values, and use `fillna()` to replace `NaN` with an empty string in the `description` column for keys that were filtered out.

Output:

```
   id category    description
0  11        A         Text_1
1  22        A
2  33        B  Text_1 Text_2
```